# How do I monitor rtsp traffic on port 554

Tags: iphone, macos, rtsp, network-traffic

Since I'm not happy with the functionality of an iPhone App that operates my Actioncam, I would like to write an app that improves on that functionality.
In order to do that, by lack of proper documentation, I need to reverse engineer the communication between the App and the Device.

What I know, is that the Device only responds on ports 21, 554 and 15740.
I managed to create a setup including an iPhone, the Device and two Macs, and traffic analyzing software called Charles (but likely I could also use Wireshark), that shows me all HTTP(S) traffic.
This is where my knowledge ends. What I hoped to see, was that Charles would report something like

```
rtsp://[my device ip, which is known to me]:554/[unknown to me path]
```

Potentially it would even involve a login and password in that URL.
Could any of you give me a hint on how to proceed? Aforementioned software seems to be limited to HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What excatly do you want to reverse engineer? The video feed or control logic? From what you mentioned it seems that 21 could be used for FTP, 554 for RTSP and 15740 for some custom TCP protocol. If you have no idea about the format of the data that is sent over to the port 15740 it will be quite hard to reverse engineer (except if it is some kind of plain text ascii protocol).

For the video feed - I'd suggest  setting up Wireshark to monitor the port 554 and then you should be able to see the url of the video location from the DESCRIBE command.

Comment: For now, I just need to find the URL, so monitoring port 554 should do the trick. I think my main task is now to start understanding Wireshark.

Comment: @Sjakelien when you start the capture set filter to "host <the host ip> and port 554", e.g - "host 192.168.1.2 and port 554". This will capture only the  traffic between you and that host on the given port. Since the default RTSP port is used Wireshark should be able to parse it and show you  the commands.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I found the URL, and now have access to the video stream. Exactly what I need!